# PHP - Problems calling a function with parameters

Tags: php

I need to call a function, in PHP, that accepts 3 parameters, RGB Values. This function converts RGB color values to HSL values, so `(R,G,B)` is needed in the parenthesis.

This is my function:

```
function RGBtoHSL($red, $green, $blue) {
  // convert colors
}
```

Which, if I make a test call of the following, it works just fine:

```
RGBtoHSL(255,0,0);
```

and also works like this:

```
RGBtoHSL(255,000,000);
```

Now, further down my page I have a variable `$displayRGB` which holds the current pixels RGB values in this format `xxx,xxx,xxx`. I've echoed this variable to test the format matches my requirements and it does, but when I try and add this variable to my function caller, it fails with the error "Missing argument 2, Missing argument 3" and points to this line:

```
RGBtoHSL($displayRGB);
```

I'm still teething in PHP (come from ASP), can somebody please help point me in the right direction and pass me my dummy?

Comment: @David - That's not how upvotes work - People upvote answers based on their merit, not when they were posted.

Comment: @David: consider yourself downvoted for being cheeky. That's not how it works.

Comment: He withdrew that comment pretty quickly buhahahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass in an array (I assume $displayRGB is an array) as "all three arguments" in PHP. Try

```
RGBtoHSL($displayRGB[0], $displayRGB[1], $displayRGB[2]);
```

or modify your function to accept an array.

If $displayRGB is a string of "xxx,yyy,zzz" you can run an explode on it

```
$colors = explode(",", $displayRGB);
```

and it will set $colors as an array with indices containing xxx, yyy and zzz.

Then pass it as I mentioned above.

Comment: I suspect that OP is providing a string, but yeah, the error is pretty clear.

Comment: Edited to reflect these comments.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it worked fine. It was a string so thanks for the edit too.

Answer (score 4):

Your `$displayRGB` is a single variable (of type string, I presume). What you can do is split this string into an array:

```
$rgbArray = explode(',', $displayRGB);
```

Then pass it to your function

```
RGBtoHSL($rgbArray[0], $rgbArray[1], $rgbArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of eval

```
call_user_func_array('RGBtoHSL', explode(',', $displayRGB));
```

Answer (score 0):

what's your $displayRGB value?

if it's "255,0,0" you should first do "explode"

e.g.

```
<?php

list($r,$g,$b)=explode(',',$displayRGB);
RGBtoHSL($r,$g,$b);
```

Comment: Nice usage of list(). I didn't think of that.

Answer (score -2):

You can't put a string in a function and expect it to explode the string for you.

You need to go like this:

```
$string = '255,0,0';
$array = explode(',', $string);
RGBtoHSL($array[0], $array[1], $array[2]);
```

Comment: -1 Should be **explode(',', $string);** with a comma. This will throw syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

I will probably get flamed for this, but this would definitely work:

```
eval("RGBtoHSL($displayRGB);");
```

Don't do it.  It will work... but don't do it.

Comment: That's funny. "Don't do it. It will work... but don't do it" totally put me off your answer. I said to myself "Don't try it". Nice one though.